# Restrict a user to SSH authentication with a key

Tags: authentication, ssh

Is there any possibility to restrict the password based authentication to a particular user in Solaris 10?

The particular user should not log in with a password. Instead he should be able to log in only with a key. I am planning to restrict user logins through SSH based on passwords and keys from another system, so that a particular user may be able to log  in with a password and a certain type of user should only be able to log in with a key.

Comment: Restrict how? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The particular user should not login with the password , instead he should be able to login only with the key.

I am planning to do restrict a user login through SSH based on password and key from another system. in that , a particular user can be able to login with password and certain type of user should be only login with the key.

Answer (score 2):

In Solaris 10, as long as you are using the "files" source for the password database in /etc/nsswitch.conf, you can prevent a user from logging in with a password by ensuring that account does not have a valid password in the /etc/shadow file. Because the mechanism for doing this inserts the literal text "NP" into the password field, it's known as "NPing the account".

The command to do this for a particular account is `passwd -N <account>`. Always use the passwd command for this purpose rather than editing the shadow file directly.

Be careful not to lock the account (`passwd -l`) as that prevents the use of keys to log in via ssh as well.

If you later decide to use some form of two-factor authentication such as SecurID or another form of RADIUS authentication (in addition to the SSH PKI), you would implement this via PAM. In this case, the password entered should be passed on to the next provider if a match with /etc/passwd fails, as it will in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if my answer might be irrelevant, but your question is somewhat unclear to me. I will give it a shot!

Since OpenSSH 5.x and later you can match certain users (**Match User**) and groups (**Match Group**) in the configuration file. I'd simply add something like this to my **sshd_config**:

> Match User rajkumar
>   PasswordAuthentication no
>   ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
>   PubkeyAuthentication yes

You could probably achieve the same result using a suitable Pluggable Authentication Module, with PAM implemented in Solaris.

Good luck!